# why $\sup$ come before $(a_n + b_n) ?$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Taken from **Rudin real and complex analysis**  book     chapter $1$ excercise

let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be  sequence  in $[-\infty,\infty]$.Prove the following assertion

$b).\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup(a_n +b_n) \le  \lim_{\to \infty} \sup a_n + \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup b_n$

My attempt : $\sup a_n$ is upper bound  of  $a_n$  and $\sup b_n$ is a upper bound of  $b_n$.

Now $ a_n \le \sup  a_n \tag1$

and  $b_n\le \sup b_n\tag2 $

From $(1)$ and $(2)$  we can say that

$a_n + b_n \le \sup a_n  + \sup b_n$

Put  limit both side

$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n + b_n \le \lim_{n \to \infty}  \sup a_n  + \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup b_n$

**My doubt** : why  $\sup$  come  before  $(a_n + b_n) ?$

Comment: Is it really $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup(a_n+b_n)$ (whatever that is), or is it $\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n):=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{m\ge n}(a_m+b_m)$?

Comment: @Gae.S. i think  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup (a_n+b_n) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{m\ge n} (a_m+b_m) $

Comment: I think you should be made aware of the existence of the latex command *limsup* for the standalone operator limsup.

Comment: Just two comments: I think many people get confused by lines like (1) and (2) where they use $n$ to mean two different things; and more important, you write $a_n\leqslant \sup a_n$ but this isn't right, it's far more complicated. To see that what you write is wrong consider the sequence $a_1=1, a_k=0 (k>1)$. Then $\limsup a_n=0$ but some $a_k>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take the supremum of a sequence you get a fixed value, so it doesn't make much sense to take the limit after it. I think you're confusing $\limsup$ and $\sup$.

They're not the same thing, since $\sup\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}\{a_n\}$ is the biggest value you can approach with the sequence (could be $+\infty$ if not bounded), while $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup\limits_{k\ge n}\{a_k\}$, which means that you consider $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$, you take the biggest value approachable and you add it to your collection; but then you consider $a_2,a_3,\ldots$, you take the biggest value approachable and you add it to your collection; now consider $a_3,\ldots$ and etc. You are collecting the biggest value approachable of each $\{a_k\}_{k\ge n}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Then you take the limit, which you can do because the way you collection is constructed is as a non-increasing sequence (you have to allow $+\infty$ as a value). Doing this you're making sure that you're getting either $+\infty$ if not bounded, either a value that your sequence doesn't stop taking or approaching to.

This is the key difference. For example: If you consider the sequence $0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,\ldots$ then the supremum is $1$, but that value just appears once, so it would be nice if there was something that makes sure we get a value that keeps appearing or a value that our sequence keeps approaching to. That's a job for $\limsup$, since eventually it gets rid of that single instance of $1$ and give us $0$, which makes sense. Another example could be the sequence $1+\frac{1}{n}$: If you consider $\sup$ you get the biggest term, which is $2$, the first one. Considering $\limsup$ you get the actual limit if the sequence, which is $1$. You can prove that if the limit of a sequence exists, then $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ give the same value as the limit.

Now, for the result you're asking about:

$a_k\le\sup\limits_{k\ge n}\{a_k\}\;\forall k\ge n$ and $b_k\le\sup\limits_{k\ge n}\{b_k\}\;\forall k\ge n$ implies $a_k+b_k\le\sup\limits_{k\ge n}\{a_k\}+\sup\limits_{k\ge n}\{b_k\}\;\forall k\ge n$, which implies $\sup\limits_{k\ge n}\{a_k+b_k\}\le\sup\limits_{k\ge n}\{a_k\}+\sup\limits_{k\ge n}\{b_k\}\;\forall k\ge n$.

Taking limit on both sides you get $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup\limits_{k\ge n}\{a_k+b_k\}\le\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\sup\limits_{k\ge n}\{a_k\}+\sup\limits_{k\ge n}\{b_k\})\le\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup\limits_{k\ge n}\{a_k\}+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sup\limits_{k\ge n}\{b_k\}=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n+\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n$

Comment: That's more like it! +1

Answer (score 1):

At this state::
$$a_{n}+b_{n}\le sup\left(a_{n}\right)+sup\left(b_{n}\right)$$
You could say that
$$c_n = (a_n+b_n)$$
is bounded from above by $sup\left(a_{n}\right)+sup\left(b_{n}\right)$
So its sup must be less or equal than this upper bound:
$$sup\left(a_{n}+b_{n}\right)\le sup\left(a_{n}\right)+sup\left(b_{n}\right)$$

Comment: But unfortunately you start at a point that isn't true without some careful restrictions put in place.

Comment: I've read your other comment, I believe you're partially right.
All these transitions are OK, until you put the limit thing, which I haven't done.

Because of your comment, I also believe the question is about 'lim sup' as lim superior and not just lim, which makes it a lot easier. I hope OP can confirm by reading the question from the book again.

Comment: Yes, I think a lot would be cleared up by using proper notation: the OP writes $\sup a_n$ which makes no sense, a real number doesn't have a "sup" and you write $\sup (a_n)$ which is equally problematic, a sequence doesn't have a sup. Only sets have sups, and writing this proof properly needs care  in specifying the sets we are taking the sups of.

Comment: That is a great notation, you are correct.
I did assume were talking about the sets of these sequences.